# sed: Search and replace varying column

Tags: bash, sed

I got a document that fields are separated by a colon(:) where I need to change the second field from time to time.  The document looks like this:

```
name1:UhX.PPFW7$YhPMH0BISY:23490::::::
name2:1./0oV$GEs6WJpE$LHXhy:19239:0:29388:2::29302:
...
```

The second field of the file will change occasionally and may contain a couple regular expression characters ($ .) and a forward slash.

I'd like to replace only the second field as the data that follows it may be different in the future.  If I do:

```
sed -e "s~^name2:.*:~name2:aTest\$repl.ace:~g" tst
```

The text to the right of the second column is lost:

```
name2:aTest$repl.ace:
```

(i.e. the '19239:0:29388:2::29302:').  Is there a way that sed can replace a varying column and preserve the rest of the line?  Or, possibly, is there a better program to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to change the .* in your regexp to match only what can actually appear in the second field, eg:

```
sed -e "s~^name2:[^:]*:~name2:aTest\$repl.ace:~g" tst
```

([^:]* == anything that doesn't contain a colon), or:

```
sed -e "s~^name2:[$./0-9a-zA-Z]*:~name2:aTest\$repl.ace:~g" tst
```

([blah]* == any number of the characters listed)

Comment: Hey that's great. Was wondering if this was possible in sed. Thought I might be looking at a more-complicated command. Appreciate the tip, Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

`Sed` probably isn't the best tool for this because if doesn't really know about fields. Consider `awk` (which has a built in concept of fields) instead:

```
$ awk -F : 'NF>=2{split($0,a,":");a[2]="new sting";printf(a[1]);for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf":%s",a[i]};printf("\n");}' <input file>
```

or formatted for readability:

```
awk -F : 'NF>=2 {
                   split($0,a,":");
                   a[2]="new sting";
                   printf(a[1]);
                   for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
                     printf":%s",a[i]
                   };
                   printf("\n");
                 }' <input file>
```

For generality you might want to replace the `":"` with `FS`. Also worth looking at is t[his `join` function](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_179.html) which would make the implementation cleaner if you a writing a script rather than running on the command line.

This implementation assumes that you want to replace *all* the second fields. If yu need to select only some of the lines for replacement, change the pattern to

```
$2=="string to match"
```

or

```
$2~/regex to match/
```

Comment: heh, awk is a bit over my head at the time but it does work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
perl -pe 's~^name2:.*?:~name2:aTest\$repl.ace:~g' test
```

Comment: Beginning to like perl - all the syntaxes it uses (that I've seen) are easy to remember syntax.  Thanks for the tip ennuikiller.